# Просмотр размера объекта в памяти

Tags: ide, java

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как как узнать размер памяти, которую занимает объект? Без JProfilerа, тк нет ключа. Есть ли какие-нибудь бесплатные средства? Интересуют плагины к IDE, желательно для Idea.

Comment: Используйте YourKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем плагин, но тем не менее: в JDK входит замечательный инструмент Java VisualVM.

Comment: вродь не входит, а отдельно качать надо

Comment: Входит-входит. Примерно тут (для виндов): 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\jvisualvm.exe`

Comment: Входит в 1.6.
Вот только как там смотреть именно память на мой объект я никак не пойму. допустим я торможу приложение в дебаге после создания моего объекта, затем коннекчусь к нему visualVMом, захожу в профайлер, нажимаю Memmory и мне выбрасывает окошко "Error", пустое. Наверняка это из-за дебага... Но как без него посмотреть сколько занимает *именно* мой объект ?

Comment: Идете в `Monitor`, снимаете дамп (`Heap Dump`), в дампе переключаетесь на `Classes`, находите свой класс, правой кнопкой, `Show in instances view`, смотрите экземпляры своего класса.

Comment: Попробовал, все равно пишет "Cannot heap dump" и не пишет почему. Может это как то с дебагом связанно ? Я делаю все как описал выше, после создания моего объекта останавливаюсь на брейкпоинте, после чего коннекчусь вмом, и дальше все как Вы описали...

Comment: Нельзя делать heap dump, если приложение застопорено на брейкпойнте.